# Fortran inverse matrix computation using SGETR(F,I) only works in single precision

Tags: fortran, fortran90, lapack, matrix-inverse, fortran95

I am trying to calculate the inverse of the square matrix but It is not working. I checked previous posts but the logic is same but I haven't still found where is the problem. I also share Matlab result for example matrix.

```
program test

Implicit none

real,allocatable,dimension(:,:)         :: A       
real,allocatable,dimension(:)           :: WORK
integer ,allocatable,dimension(:)       :: ipiv
integer                                 :: n,info,M
external     SGETRF,SGETRI
M=8
allocate(A(M,M),WORK(M),IPIV(M))

A(1,:)=(/3.74E-4, 0.0, 0.0, 4.98E-5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0/)
A(2,:)=(/0.0 , 3.74E-4, 0.0, 0.0, 4.98E-5 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 /)
A(3,:)=(/0.0 , 0.0 ,3.74E-4, 0.0 ,0.0, 4.98E-5, 0.0 ,0.0/)
A(4,:)=(/4.98E-5 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,6.64e-6, 0.0 ,0.0, 0.0, 0.0 /)
A(5,:)=(/0.0 , 4.98E-5, 0.0, 0.0 ,6.64E-6 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 /)
A(6,:)=(/0.0, 0.0, 4.98E-5, 0.0 ,0.0, 6.64E-6, 0.0 ,0.0 /)
A(7,:)=(/0.0, 0.0 ,0.0, 0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,1.49E-11, 0.0 /)
A(8,:)=(/0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0 ,0.0, 0.0 ,1.49E-11 /)


call SGETRF(M,M,A,M,IPIV,info)
if(info .eq. 0) then
   Print *,'succeded'
else
   Print *,'failed'
end if

call SGETRI(M,A,M,IPIV,WORK,M,info)
if(info .eq. 0) then
  Print *,'succeded'
else
  Print *,'failed'
end if
Print *,A

deallocate(A,IPIV,WORK)

end 

!!!!! Matlab Result
!1.0e+10 *
! 0.0002     0       0   -0.0015       0      0        0   0
!     0      0.0002  0       0       -0.0015  0        0   0
!     0      0    0.0002     0         0     -0.0015   0   0
! -0.0015    0       0     0.0113      0      0        0   0
!     0     -0.0015  0       0       0.0113   0        0   0
!     0      0   -0.0015     0         0    0.0113     0   0
!     0      0       0       0         0      0     6.7114 0
!     0      0       0       0         0      0        0   6.7114
```

Comment: Please keep the question as it is because it has an accepted answer now. Do not rewrite the code with the new question because you now have your new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833567/fortran-inverse-matrix-result-not-correct-for-double-precision for that. Keep it in the new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `reals` are only single precision.  The lapack `D` prefix implies double precision.  Two fixes:

1. Change your `DG`s to `SG`s
2. Keep your `DG`s and use double precision

Comment: I changed for double precision but result is not correct but for single precision is working!

Comment: Based on the new question title it seems you are attempting to call the single precision lapack routines with double precision data.  Is that correct?

Comment: The case is ill condition for matrix. It is also working for double precision but the result is little bit strange. After inverse matrix, I will decompose the matrix by cholesky decomposition.but if i do , matrix is singular not nonsingular.