# Fortran- Inverse Matrix result not same if Decimal is longer

Tags: matrix, fortran, fortran90, matrix-inverse, fortran95

My real data is first input but inverse of result is so big. They are same data when you compare with first and second input. There is only difference decimal size. Why is there different result? Because they are same data. How can they have different result? You can see result and input. It is so strange.

```
program test

Implicit none

double precision,allocatable,dimension(:,:)         :: A       
double precision,allocatable,dimension(:)           :: WORK
integer ,allocatable,dimension(:)       :: ipiv
integer                                 :: n,info,M
 external     DGETRF,DGETRI
M=8
allocate(A(M,M),WORK(M),IPIV(M))
!!! First Input !!!!
A(1,:)=(/3.740486048842566D-4, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 4.987315029057229D-5, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 0.0D0/)
A(2,:)=(/0.0D0 , 3.740486048842566D-4, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 4.987315029057229D-5 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 /)
A(3,:)=(/0.0D0 , 0.0D0 ,3.740486048842566D-4, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 4.987315029057229D-5, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0/)
A(4,:)=(/4.987315029057229D-5 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,6.649753768432517D-6, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 0.0D0, 0.0D0 /)
A(5,:)=(/0.0D0 , 4.987315029057229D-5, 0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,6.649753768432517D-6 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 /)
A(6,:)=(/0.0D0, 0.0D0, 4.987315029057229D-5, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 6.649753768432517D-6, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0 /)
A(7,:)=(/0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,1.499999910593033D-11, 0.0D0 /)
A(8,:)=(/0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,1.499999910593033D-11 /)
 !!!! Second Input !!!! 
!A(1,:)=(/3.74D-4, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 4.98D-5, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 0.0D0/)
!A(2,:)=(/0.0D0 , 3.74D-4, 0.0D0, 0.0D0, 4.98D-5 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 /)
!A(3,:)=(/0.0D0 , 0.0D0 ,3.74D-4, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 4.98D-5, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0/)
!A(4,:)=(/4.98D-5 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,6.64D-6, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 0.0D0, 0.0D0 /)
!A(5,:)=(/0.0D0 , 4.98D-5, 0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,6.64D-6 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 /)
!A(6,:)=(/0.0D0, 0.0D0, 4.98D-5, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 6.64D-6, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0 /)
!A(7,:)=(/0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,1.49D-11, 0.0D0 /)
!A(8,:)=(/0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0 ,0.0D0, 0.0D0 ,1.49D-11 /)


call DGETRF(M,M,A,M,IPIV,info)
if(info .eq. 0) then
Print *,'succeded'
else
Print *,'failed'
end if

call DGETRI(M,A,M,IPIV,WORK,M,info)
if(info .eq. 0) then
 Print *,'succeded'
else
Print *,'failed'
end if
Print *,A

deallocate(A,IPIV,WORK)

end 
!!!!! Second Input Result
!1.0e+10 *
! 0.0002     0       0   -0.0015       0      0        0   0
!     0      0.0002  0       0       -0.0015  0        0   0
!     0      0    0.0002     0         0     -0.0015   0   0
! -0.0015    0       0     0.0113      0      0        0   0
!     0     -0.0015  0       0       0.0113   0        0   0
!     0      0   -0.0015     0         0    0.0113     0   0
!     0      0       0       0         0      0     6.7114 0
!     0      0       0       0         0      0        0   6.7114

!!! First Input Result
!   1.0e+21 *

!-0.0238         0         0    0.1783         0         0         0         0
!     0   -0.0238         0         0    0.1783         0         0         0
!     0         0    0.0000         0         0   -0.0000         0         0
! 0.1783         0         0   -1.3375         0         0         0         0
!     0    0.1783         0         0   -1.3375         0         0         0
!     0         0   -0.0000         0         0    0.0000         0         0
!     0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0000         0
!     0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0000
```

Comment: You have to tell us what does it mean *"wrong"*. What are your results? What are the correct results? Try a simple matrix for which you know the exact solution or just compare your results with the Matlab results. But show us the comparison.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks I change it. The problem is decimal size. How can change the result?

Comment: But would should be the correct result? Why do you think the current result is wrong?

Comment: they are same number and magnitude are almost same How can they be different? Also , the difference is 10^10.

Comment: The are not almost the same, they differ considerably!

Comment: But they are so small number. Only difference decimal size. How can be big difference?

Comment: If the matrix is ill-conditioned a small change will mean large change in the result. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices

Comment: Thanks I will check and try to find some example

Comment: The problem with this matrix is the condition number. If you look at the eigenvalues of both matrices, their magnitude ranges from `1E-4` to `1E-21`. This indicates that for both matrices you have a condition number of about `1E17`. The bigger this number, the harder it is to invert the matrix numerically. As a general rule of thumb, if the condition number is `1Ek`, then you may lose up to `k` digits of accuracy (double precision goes up to `1E-17`). More [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261295/to-invert-a-matrix-condition-number-should-be-less-than-what) and wiki.

Comment: This question should be migrated to https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @kvantour Thanks I will check math.stackexchange !

Answer (score 2):

Creating a matrix inverse is not a difficult problem.
I converted your earlier example to using a simple approach, based on Gaussian elimination with a shadowed identity matrix, which works well for most cases. The attached program inverts your earlier symmetric matrix, without resorting to pivoting of the rows. It does not need a "black-box".

That you get different results with different coefficients is hardly surprising. With the significant change in results for apparently small changes of input values, shows the sensitivity and possibly poor conditioning of the equation relationship you are using.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssotjx45yrz5sf9/dgetri.f90?dl=0

Additional response re "First Input"

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hximfoin977rmov/dgetri_piv4.f90?dl=0

This latest link (16-6) has both data sets included. In "First Input", your equations basically are rows 4:6 are rows 1:3 / 7.5 + small_noise.

This latest code example has accuracy checks both during the matrix inversion and also after. The during test checks the row changes are correct, while the after checks are "A.A^-1 - I" and "A - (A^-1)^-1", which better indicate poor accuracy.

It is interesting that "Second Input" (with more noise) reports a reasonably accurate outcome. Failing to get an inverse with 8-byte reals needs a fairly contrived matrix ! Similarly, the random number derived coefficients examples shows good accuracy.

These examples show that the accuracy tests I have presented don't always identify poorly defined equation relationships. Your inspection of the inverse to identify large variation in values is also useful.

Given the way the equations appear to have been defined, I am not sure what is the outcome you are wanting.

Comment: Thanks for this code. Also so nice example for inverse matrix. not need to use Black-box :) But I think the problem is `ill-conditioned`. Because, after I am trying to get `cholesky decomposition` so that matrix is singular!

Comment: Cholesky decomposition requires a positive definite matrix, so can be restrictive. You have given multiple example matrices, although the one I considered was not singular. I have included partial pivoting, which can be useful for general matrices, although most practical matrices I have are symmetric and non-singular. Before Fortran 90, creating temporary arrays was an issue, but since, most matrix inversion is a non-issue. The inverted matric can be convenient, especially in least squares calculations.

Comment: Exactly, cholesky requıres posıtıve definite but the matrice is not PD so I wıll check @kvantour comment.

Comment: the attached link is to the modified example with partial pivoting. I have included more tests for accuracy, which may be of interest. The link is [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tq4oqg4u1dqv7a/dgetri_piv.f90?dl=0)  You would have to get to large matrices (say m >> 1000)  before the inefficiency of modifying a shadowed identity matrix becomes impractical. At this stage sparsity and reducing to upper triangular form could be considered.

Comment: `max error in A - (A^-1)^-1 =1.1805916207174113E+021`  I got thıs result from your code for fırst input.

Comment: @nobody I got `max error in A - (A^-1)^-1 =    1.9840899756484731E-017` using gFortran 7.2.0 64-bit and `max error in A - (A^-1)^-1 =        2.260561529632E-17` using Silverfrost FTN95 32-bit

Comment: I have now looked at your "first example" : row_1 = 7.5 * row_4; row_2 = 7.5*row_5 & row_3 = 7.5*row_6, so the accuracy test is showing a problem. The new link, including this data set is [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hximfoin977rmov/dgetri_piv4.f90?dl=0)

Comment: @But thıs ıs for the second ınput can you chack for first input? I will try to how can convert to Posititive definite because the input data is not non positive definite

Comment: I would be good to provide the codes directly in your response, rather than in a Dropbox link which would be likely broken in a week.